# How do I segue back to the main storyboard after verifying app with Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am using a third party view controller to verify my app with firebase.
It works perfectly to create a user using their phone number but after creating an account, it just stays on the input phone number storyboard. How can I have it segue back to the main.storyboard after a phone number is verified.

The third party is: https://github.com/appwise-labs/PhoneVerificationController/blob/master/README.md

Here is the code from my view controller.swift:

```
@IBAction func onLoginButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

let configuration = Configuration(requestCode: { phone, completion in
    PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phone, uiDelegate: nil, completion: completion)
}, signIn: { verificationID, verificationCode, completion in
    let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID: verificationID, verificationCode: verificationCode)
    Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential) { _, error in completion(error) }
})
let vc = PhoneVerificationController(configuration: configuration)
    vc.delegate = self as? PhoneVerificationDelegate
present(vc, animated: true)

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the delegate methods

```
extension ViewController: PhoneVerificationDelegate {
    func cancelled(_ controller: PhoneVerificationController) {
        print("Cancelled verification")
        controller.dismiss(animated: true)
    }

    func verified(_ phoneNumber: String, controller: PhoneVerificationController) {
        print("Verified phone \(phoneNumber)")
        controller.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

And replace this

```
vc.delegate = self as? PhoneVerificationDelegate
```

with

```
vc.delegate = self
```

Comment: Do I just add this code to a new ViewController or to the main view controller? Thank you for the help!

Comment: Add the above extension only replace `ViewController` with your vc  name that contains `onLoginButtonPressed`